# Outlook Options not saving

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, encryption

I'm running outlook 2007.  Yesterday out of the blue, my security settings stopped working.  I went to Tools -> Options -> Security tab, and unchecked box to Encrypt contents and attachments for outgoing messages.  As soon as I hit apply, it immediately reverts that box back to its checked status.

When I hit send, it also pops up the encryption options, at which point I uncheck the Encrypt message contents and attachments, and also check the Do not ask me to confirm message security again.  All of this to no avail...

The only resolution I've seemed to have [is to create a new profile](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-outlook/ol-2007-is-not-saving-changes-to-security-settings/75083468-0ffb-4ad8-8380-b77fddecc6cd).  Has anyone else discovered a different solution?

Answer (score 0):

Is the system on a domain?  Perghaps this is managed by GPO?

Has there been a change in the account you use? Limited user or ?

Comment: I am on a domain, and an updated policy did come to mind.  I am an administrator on this machine, I'm also one of the few on Windows 7, so I can't just ask anyone in the organization whether this has started occurring for them recently or if their newer image had this by default.